# Folders and files in desktop show their full path

Tags: 14.04

This has been a problem for me for a long while now. I believe it began after one update. The folders and files in my desktop show their full path after their name like this:

[image].

For example, if I have a folder called Pictures, in my desktop the name would show like:

```
Pictures /home/$USER$/Desktop
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Ah, sorry, I misread your question, the path *shows* on the items, which you do not want.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem after I played with *Nautilus* (The file manager application) settings.

Just open Nautilus and go to *Edit* --> *Preferences*. From the *Display* tab, select *None* instead of *Location* from the *Icon Captions* section. Go to the desktop and hit F5.